# when do I need to use dialogfragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have **fragment** with button after pressing that button it should open **AlertDialog** which has two buttons with images, one image for each button (no text on buttons). One Dialog button opens Gallery to pick photo and pass it back to **fragment** other opens camera to take photos and pass it to same fragment. So should I use **DialogFragment** for that or I can create **AlertDialog** in that **fragment** and it will be ok? I just don't get it when do I need to use DialogFragments

Comment: This is the same as asking: `Do I need Fragments? Or would Activities work for me?`

Comment: So it is for efficiency.

Comment: And for coherence, as well (which is much appreciated). Since you are using Fragments all over your app, why not continuing on that lane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"DialogFragment does various things to keep the fragment's lifecycle driving it, instead of the Dialog. Note that dialogs are generally autonomous entities -- they are their own window, receiving their own input events, and often deciding on their own when to disappear (by receiving a back key event or the user clicking on a button)."

*Source : Dialog Fragments | Android Developers*

"This is easy.

DialogFragment is a fragment. So what can a fragment provide you while other objects can't?

It's the lifecycle callbacks.

So with DialogFragment, it can be very powerful and makes your code much cleaner.

Have you ever seen window leaks if you didn't close a dialog when its Activity was getting destroyed? So to prevent that, have you ever tried to close the dialog when onPause() was called? So to do that, have you ever had to make a reference of that dialog to a class level object?

With DialogFragment, it's all handled.
And you get all lifecycle callbacks.
Then you can provide more intelligence to the dialog and make it do some smart work on its own rather than Activity telling it what to do."

*Source : KoreanDude | StackOverflow*